# Updated GRUB on Arch Linux, tried fix but GRUB gives error: Symbol grub_debug_malloc not found

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, uefi, grub2-mkconfig

I posted this same post on r/archlinux but have not gotten much results.

I updated Arch Linux (vanilla), but now GRUB boots into firmware. 
(I am sure a lot of you guys have known this issue,
and I did know about this prior to updating,
but when I updated it, the fix didn't work in my environment.)

I am currently posting this inside of the EndeavourOS Live environment.

I have chrooted:

```
sudo mount <root partition> /mnt
sudo mount <efi partition> /mnt/boot/efi
sudo arch-chroot /mnt
```

<sup><sup>(Replaced `<root partition>` with my root partition
and `<efi partition>` with my EFI partition
because, obviously, I am running UEFI.)</sup></sup>

and I have reinstalled GRUB thanks to [this post](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/the-latest-grub-package-update-needs-some-manual-intervention/30689) by sradjoker
on the EndeavourOS Forum.

```
grub-install
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and GRUB gives this error:

```
error: symbol grub_debug_malloc not found
```

GRUB then puts me in GRUB rescue. 
As I understand it, some files are missing. 
I tried this same process multiple times, but it still did not work.

Is there a fix? Do I need to reinstall Arch Linux?

Comment: When exactly does the `error: symbol grub_debug_malloc not found` message appear? Does it show up when you run `grub-install`, or when you run `grub-mkconfig`, or does it appear when you are trying to boot?

Comment: @telcoM after all thr commands are run and a reboot is done.

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with the boot order in this case, so grub is choosing the incorrect one... I'm trying to find out why the option with `efibootmgr` https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/the-latest-grub-package-update-needs-some-manual-intervention/30689 from here is not becoming persistent after reboot

Comment: If the configuration made by `efibootmgr` does not "stick", it might be a firmware bug. [Roderick W. Smith has listed some workarounds for such situations.](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) His advice is written for the rEFInd boot manager, but the ideas should be mostly applicable to UEFI version of GRUB too.